# Leer Macro Excel con Varias Hojas y Convertir a Pdf PHp

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un pequeño software de envio de notificaciones donde se van a cargar macros excel y se van a leer y dependiendo del proceso se carga en bse de datos o se convierten a pdf y se envian como adjunto.

Tengo un problema leyendo una macro de excel que va a tener (N) cantidad de hojas, las cuales tengo que leer y por cada hoja generar un pdf.

Tengo un ejemplo que estoy tratando de implementar donde puedo cread un pdf mas no se como decirle mira de esta macro solo crea un Pdf de la hoja 1, adicionalmente cuando genera el pdf el codigo lo genera vacio y con error.

cabe destacar que junior con php y no estoy usando framework, mi servidor es wamp y la version de php  8.0.26

```
        $RutaPdf = 'C:/wamp/www/ProyectoCondominio- 
        copia/ArchivosCargaMasiva/Recibos/PdfGenerados/A.pdf';
        $reader = IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load("C:/wamp/www/ProyectoCondominio- 
        copia/ArchivosCargaMasiva/Destinatarios/ListadoDeCorreos.xlsx"); 
        

        //Conversion del la variable spreadsheet in pdf
            //Creando la escritura
            $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Tcpdf');
            if(!file_exists($RutaPdf)){
            $pdf_path = $RutaPdf;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $pdf_path;
            $writer->save($pdf_path);
            }
            //Salvataggio del pfd
            //$pdf_path = 'pdf_finali/'.$name.'.pdf';
            
            //$writer->save($pdf_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

el error en el código anterior era que en el proyecto no tenia la librería de  [tcpdf](/questions/tagged/tcpdf)